# How to count specific variables from Joined tables

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables.

business unit

```
ID unit
1  AR
2  AP
3  AT HOME
4  CSS
5  EIT
6  SUPPORT
```

asset_item

```
ID allocation_unit item_type
1  AR              Laptop
2  AP              Laptop
3  CSS             Laptop
4  EIT             Laptop
5  EIT             Laptop
6  EIT             Laptop
```

I wanted to be able to pull up data into a table where in I can count how many Laptops has all the business units

This is the result I wanted to show

```
Unit     Laptop
AR       1
AP       1
AT HOME  0
CSS      1
EIT      3
SUPPORT  0
```

Comment: Please show some attempt that you have made to solve this for yourself. This isn't a place to come and just dump your requirements and expect everything to be done for you.

Comment: Sorry @PatrickQ, i have tried solving it by myself. I am not expert in PHP that's why I came here to ask for a help for those who are willing to help.

Comment: So like I said, show your attempt.  Describe the result and/or any errors that you encountered.  On the face of it, this is more of an SQL question than a PHP question.  But without seeing exactly where you're having trouble, we can't really say for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a `LEFT JOIN` from the `business_unit` table to the `asset_item` accordingly. `business_unit` table should be the leftmost table, since you want to consider all the `unit`, even if there is not matching rows in the `asset_item`.

We can then `GROUP BY` and use conditional aggregation on `COUNT()` function:

```
SELECT
  bu.unit, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN ai.item_type = 'Laptop' THEN 1 END) AS Laptop
FROM business_unit bu 
LEFT JOIN asset_item ai 
  ON ai.allocation_unit = bu.unit 
GROUP BY bu.unit
```

---

If you are only concerned with `Laptop` count values, then we can put the condition on `LEFT JOIN` itself and do away with the `CASE..WHEN` expression.

```
SELECT
  bu.unit, 
  COUNT(ai.item_type) AS Laptop
FROM business_unit bu 
LEFT JOIN asset_item ai 
  ON ai.allocation_unit = bu.unit AND 
     ai.item_type = 'Laptop' 
GROUP BY bu.unit
```

Comment: Thanks Madhur, I was able to pull up the record of the Unit from business unit but I am not able to pull up the counts.

Comment: Here's the code
`<?php
    include '../db_config/connection.php';
    $sql = "SELECT
  bu.unit, 
  COUNT(ai.item_type) AS Laptop
FROM business_unit bu 
LEFT JOIN asset_item ai 
  ON ai.allocation_unit = bu.unit AND 
     ai.item_type = 'Laptop' 
GROUP BY bu.unit";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row['unit']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['item_type']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>`

Comment: Really appreciate the help regarding this Madhur. I only have one problem now. to pull up the counts per unit. Should I use mysqli_num_rows? if yes how should I pull up the data? Thank you so much!

Comment: @jackflick use `echo $row['Laptop']` to get the count

Comment: I have one more question @Madhur Bhaiya, What if I wanted to show it up like this.

`AP AR AT HOME CSS EIT SUPPORT
0    0    0               0       3    0`

The units are on <thead> and the counts are below the thead? 
I've tried changing the setup but it is not showing the way it supposed to show.